# Checking if email already exists in the database

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to check whether the e-mail address already exists in the database, at the outset, I would like to mention that NO code from the internet does not work. So please quick help and understanding as a matter of programming I'm pretty green. Here's the basic information about the call, etc.

```
 string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=admin;password=admin";

string query = "select * from test.user where email='" + emailtextbox.Text + "';";

MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmddatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDatabase);
```

The column in which emails are called "email".

Comment: Consider using prepared statements over string concatenation for creating queries. Also, you can use `Count` instead of fetching * from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
string query = "select * from test.user where replace(email,' ','')='"
+ emailtextbox.Text.Trim() + "'";

MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmddatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDatabase);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:** You can `Trim` the `EmailID` enetered by user and then compare.

Try This:

```
string query = "select count(*) from test.user where email = @email";

MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);

MySqlCommand cmddatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDatabase);
cmddatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",emailtextbox.Text.Trim());

conDatabase.Open();
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmddatabase.ExecuteScalar());

if(count > 0)
{
    // yes emailid exists already
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even if the entry exists, that is, the email appears that the e-mail address does not exist

Comment: @user3310916: sorry i didn't get you.